# Subtraction of arrays elements in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

please see my code below :

```
package calc;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[]numbers= {6 , 5 ,7};
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        double diff = numbers[3-1];
        for (int i =2 ; i<= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            diff-=numbers[i-1];
        }
        System.out.println("Answer --> "+diff);
    }
}
```

My problem is that i am trying to subtract the elements in the array. I have assumed that the user have inserted the values randomly , so i have sorted the array and i have iterated the array "inversely" (From the highest index to the lower one) , so that i can subtract like this --> 7-6-5=-4 . Unfortunately the for loop is not executed , can someone tell me what is the problem here  ? Thanks

Comment: What is with the `> ` in your code and its lack of proper formatting for readability? You're not new here and should know better, no?

Comment: what do you think `double diff = numbers[3-1];` is doing?

Comment: `i <= 0` should be `i >= 0`. Quickly delete the question before someone types this up as an answer :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Yes i am not new here , but this is the first time i am learning java , this example is for training and learning only .  This is the first java code for me , so for sure its not perfect .

Comment: @ahmed: I was referring to your posted code. It was unreadable until dasblinken fixed its formatting. I was trying to fix it myself, but was having great difficulty given how jumbled things are. Please take greater care in the future.

Comment: oh  , sorry for that i am facing some difficulties here with my computer . Thank you and sorry for the misunderstanding bro :)

Comment: Thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your looping.

```
    double[]numbers= {6 , 5 ,7};
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    // start with last number
    double diff = numbers[numbers.length-1];
    for (int i=numbers.length-2 ; i>= 0; i--) {
      // substract other number one by one  
      diff-=numbers[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Answer --> "+diff);
```

Comment: Not you're down-voter, but you don't want to answer a low-quality question with a low-quality answer

Comment: what is wrong why downvote?

Comment: at the end help is important not matter what privilege i have

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: yes i put comment in code so he can understand loop.

Comment: Thanks @DevramKandhare

Comment: you are always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The for loop is not executed because of the conditions in your loop statement.

Right now, you have `int i=2; i <= 0; i--`. When Java goes to execute this loop, it finds that `i=2` which is not `<= 0`, so the loop is never executed.

To make the loop execute, change `i <= 0` to `i >= 0`